# what's wrong with the usage of react-wordcloud

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, word-cloud

version

- react: 17.0.0
- react-wordcloud: 1.2.7

For now, I wrote the following code to display WordCloud.

```js
import React, { VFC } from "react"
import ReactWordcloud, { Word, Options } from 'react-wordcloud'

const testwords: Word[] = [
  {
    text: 'told',
    value: 64,
  },
  {
    text: 'mistake',
    value: 11,
  },
  {
    text: 'thought',
    value: 16,
  },
  {
    text: 'bad',
    value: 17,
  },
  {
    text: 'INO',
    value: 30,
  },
]
  
type WordCloudProps = {
 
}

export const WordCloud: VFC<WordCloudProps> = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div style={{ height: "100%", width: "100%" }}>
        <ReactWordcloud
          words={testwords}      
        />
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Technically, the header is in front of the ReactWordCloud component, but I wrote it almost exactly like this.
This is what the main page is trying to receive and display.
testwords are the official sample data.
[react-wordcloud](https://github.com/chrisrzhou/react-wordcloud)

However, when I run this, I don't get any errors, but nothing is displayed.

So I checked the elements in the browser.
If you see the one that is working correctly, it looks like this.

```html
<svg height="390.5" width="396" style="display: block;">
  <g transform="translate(198, 195.25)">
    <text cursor="default" fill="#BCBD22" font-family="times new roman" font-style="normal" font-weight="normal" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(19, -43)" font-size="32px">Parkinson's</text>
    <text cursor="default" fill="#8C564B" font-family="times new roman" font-style="normal" font-weight="normal" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(75, -70)" font-size="26px">PD</text>
    ...
  </g>
</svg>
```

I looked at the same part of the output from my code and found the following.

```html
<svg height="396.5" width="1265" style="display: block;">
  <g transform="translate(632.5, 198.25)">
    <text cursor="default" fill="#17becf" font-family="times new roman" font-style="normal" font-weight="normal" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0, 0) rotate(0)"></text>
    <text cursor="default" fill="#1f77b4" font-family="times new roman" font-style="normal" font-weight="normal" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0, 0) rotate(0)"></text>
    <text cursor="default" fill="#17becf" font-family="times new roman" font-style="normal" font-weight="normal" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0, 0) rotate(0)"></text>
    <text cursor="default" fill="#7f7f7f" font-family="times new roman" font-style="normal" font-weight="normal" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0, 0) rotate(0)"></text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

There is nothing in the text tag, and the positional information and font-size are empty.
However, the number of text tags matches the number of elements in the testwords, so it looks like it is trying to load the testwords but is not able to process them.

I'm having trouble understanding why this is happening.
If anyone has any ideas, please let me know.

Comment: I updated the basic example on the RWC page with your data [and it does appear to work](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-wordcloud-basic-forked-7krmq).

Comment: Thanks for your advice!
I've almost figured out the cause.
It seems that it was not caused by the grammar, but by the dependency of the library.
It seems that D3-transition also depends on other libraries, and the cause was that multiple libraries were installed due to different dependency versions.